# Use of dictionary for file-saving function

Tags: python, hash-map

I have the following function:

```
def save_to_file(data, columns_order, save_filename):
    """ Saves data to file
    :param data: data to be saved
    :param columns_order: the order of columns
                          if needed to rearrange
                          else put ""
    :param save_filename: the filename (csv, xls, xlsx)
    :return: True if done or None if error
    """
    try:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        if columns_order:  # Rearrange columns if needed
            df = df[columns_order]
        if save_filename.endswith(".csv"):  # Save as csv
            df.to_csv(save_filename, index=False)
            return True
        elif any(save_filename.endswith(ext) for ext in [".xls", ".xlsx"]):  # Save as xls or xlsx
            df.to_excel(save_filename)
            return True
        else:
            print "Choose between csv, xls, xlsx."
            return None
    except Exception, e:
        print "Save_to_file error:", e
        return None
```

I don't know if I should leave it like that or put the functions in a dictionary:

```
func_dict = {".csv": df.to_csv(save_filename, index=False), ".xlsx:": df.to_excel(save_filename)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could reduce duplication (and make it easier to add new exporters) if you used a dictionary to map extensions to functions. However, you couldn't do it quite as you suggest; you would store *the result of the method call* in the dictionary, not the method itself. Here is one suggestion, using [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to get the extension defined in `save_filename` and [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to supply the additional argument required for CSVs.

```
from functools import partial
import os

EXPORTERS = {'.xls': pd.DataFrame.to_excel,
             '.xlsx': pd.DataFrame.to_excel,
             '.csv': partial(pd.DataFrame.to_csv, index=False)}

def save_to_file(data, save_filename, columns_order=None):
    """ Saves data to file

    :param data: data to be saved
    :param save_filename: the filename
    :param columns_order: the order of columns
                          if needed to rearrange

    :return: True if done or None if error

    """
    try:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        if columns_order is not None:  # Rearrange columns if needed
            df = df[columns_order]
        _, ext = os.path.splitext(save_filename)
        if ext in EXPORTERS:
            EXPORTERS[ext](df, save_filename)
            return True
        else:
            print "Not a supported filetype: {}".format(ext)
    except Exception, e:
        print "Save_to_file error:", e
```

Note the following:

- I have stored the methods on the class in the dictionary, allowing it to be defined outside the function, so you need to pass the instance `df` as well as the first argument `save_filename`;
- Rather than force the user to specify `""` if the `columns_order` isn't required, I have given it a default `None` value; and
- `return None` is implicit.

Including the list of supported filetypes in the docstring and output message is duplication of the information now stored in the dictionary's keys - if you add another supported type, you now need to change three parts of your code.

Finally, you should review your error handling. For one thing, `except Exception as e:` is more modern than `except Exception, e:` (which is retained on;ly for backwards compatibility, and doesn't work at all in 3.x). Secondly, you should use more specific error handling - what could go wrong, and how should it be dealt with? At the very least, I would differentiate between:

1. The conversion to `DataFrame` or column rearrangement not working; and
2. A failure in file operations.

Thirdly, rather than `return` either `True` or `None`, it would be conventional to raise an error from your function in the cases where you currently `print` a message - if the data hasn't been saved, the calling function should do something about it - and `return None` (again, implicitly) otherwise.

Comment: We should use `except Exception as e:` instead of `except Exception, e:`. The latter is present only for backwards compatibility in Python 2.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary good point, updated

Comment: You would use multiple excepts statements for the errors ?

Comment: @evil_inside and more, shorter `try` blocks, yes.